# Hibernate DAO doesn't insert row into database MyEclipse

Tags: java, hibernate, dao

I'm trying to insert a new object into my database. I followed a step-by-step tutorial but it seems it doesn't work for me. In the tutorial  there was the following line :

Transaction tx = dao.GetSession().beginTransaction();

The GetSession doesn't pop up, i get the error "GetSession() is not visible from DaoHibernateSupport".
I replaced the line with the following :

```
Transaction tx = dao.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();
```

but then i got a null Exception on the currentSession.

I read online and added the `current_session_context property`, set as "`thread`".

Everything seems to work now, i don 't get any Exception but still no rows are inserted into my MySql database. The table is InnoDB.

Here is my final code:

```
         Banner banner = new Banner();

     banner.setUrl(url);

     banner.setCategorie(categorie);

     banner.setCuvinteCheie(cuvinte_cheie);

     banner.setMaxCpc(cpc);

     banner.setPath(cale);

     banner.setPaththumb(caleThumb);

     banner.setAdvertiserId(Integer.parseInt(session.getAttribute("UserID").toString()));

     BannerDAO dao = new BannerDAO();

     SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

     dao.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);

     Transaction tx = dao.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();

     dao.save(banner);

     tx.commit();

     dao.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().close();
```

- So no exceptions raised here, but when i access the database there are no rows in the table.

  Can you please help me ? 
  Thank you!

Comment: Maybe the problem is in the Banner-class, if you annotated it wrong.

Comment: @ user714965 well, i used Hibernate Reverse Engineering in MyEclipse so the class where automatically created. Aren't they supposed to be correct? I looked into the banner class everything seems ok.

Comment: @Bozho i'm guessing save() saves ( or it should save)  the banner into the database. Also part of the DAO class

Comment: isn't the dao your code?

Comment: No, all 3 classes are created when i use hibernate reverse engenneering on a dtabase table. I get :AbstractBanner, DAOBanner, and Banner classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. When i used reverse engineering in MyEclipse i created a SpringDAO instead of BasicDAO. Now the method getSession() works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You may try

```
Transaction tx = dao.getSessionFactory().openSession().beginTransaction();
```

instead of

```
Transaction tx = dao.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();
```

Comment: what do you mean ? i didn't write any query.